# i am facing issue with error import lungc

Tags: python, import

iM getting an error of  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lungc'

```
import cv2
import lungc
import pickle

num=input("Enter test image number: ")
img=cv2.imread("test/test ("+num+").jpg",0)
left_feature,right_feature,img_left,img_right=lungc.process_lung_test(img)


filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
result = loaded_model.predict([left_feature])
print(result[0])
if(result[0]):
    print("Tumour present")
else:
    print("Normal Lung")
```

GETTING ERROR

*ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
1 import cv2
----> 2 import lungc
3 import pickle
4
5 num=input("Enter test image number: ")
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lungc'*

Comment: Python don't seem to find the `lungc` module. Do you have it installed, what is your version of Python, maybe your os ?

Answer (score 0):

have you created the module lungc yourself or installed it because it does not exist in the pypi